# Can't run Python 3.6.3 through an application on server

Tags: azure, python

I'm a total newbie about servers, but I'm trying run python through an application on the server(Azure) so that when I work on the local application, I can connect to the server and run Python codes through the app.

However, after some testing, I can only successfully run Python 2.7 through the app, but not 3.6.3. I've contacted the application support, they confirmed that I should be able to run 3.6.3 on the server, however, I can't, getting the error code -1. The log files from the application don't tell much information.

I have tried to repair Python3, install only Python3 on server, install both Python2 and 3 on the server, but in vain, only Python2 works...

This is a hopeless try actually, cause I am stuck to find out what caused Python 3.6 not working. Please let me know if anything I could look into or try out to make it work. Thank you very much!

Comment: What python is being pointed to in the path for the user/service running the app?

Comment: Hi @CtrlDot, I think whatever the default python is on the server. The command would be `python python-script.py {inputpath} {outputpath}`, so my impression is whatever the default python is on the server would run. Did I miss any steps?